# Defining a JavaScript object in console

Tags: javascript, json, oop, google-chrome, v8

When I type simple objects to Chrome JavaScript Console, I get an output like this:

```
>true
true
>1/3
0.3333333333333333
```

And so on.

But a syntax error occurs when I type objects:

```
>{ a: 1, b: 2 }
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
arguments: Array[1]
0: ":"
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
get message: function getter() { [native code] }
get stack: function getter() { [native code] }
set message: function setter() { [native code] }
set stack: function setter() { [native code] }
type: "unexpected_token"
__proto__: Error
```

While I know for sure that this expression could be correctly used in initializing an object, because:

```
>obj = { a: 1, b: 2 }
Object
a: 1
b: 2
__proto__: Object
```

Maybe it's a silly question, but I really want to know the reason why is this happening?

Comment: I know enough to tell you that this is because JavaScript is very particular about what is a valid expression and what is not. For example, `function foo(){}` is a _Function Declaration_ but `(function foo(){})` is a _Function Expression_ due to the syntax rules, and they have different functional implications. I don't know the spec enough to point you to the exact wording that disallows `{}`  as an expression but allows `({})` (try it!), but I do know the spec's insanity enough to tell you that that answer will likely just make you say "Huh. OK.".

Comment: The best answer you're likely to get is similar to the _reason_ that `+[]` equals `0`, but `+[]+[]` equals the string `"0"`. The reason is _"because that's what the spec says to do"_, without any great insight into _why_ the spec authors chose to make that decision.

Comment: Interestingly, typing just `{a:1}` results in `1`, again due to a different interpretation of what that happens to be. A great answer might also include why this is the case. An epic answer would show what confusion/conflict might occur if this expression were interpreted as we expect.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem unless I add an index after the object, as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48548444/javascript-grammar-indexing-object-literals-syntactically-forbidden#48548476 Has the console parser changed since 2012?

Comment: Yes, it's changed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36438289/864233

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because your statement is being evaluated as a [*block*](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.1), not an object literal declaration.

> Note that an ExpressionStatement cannot start with an opening curly brace because that might make it ambiguous with a Block. Also, an ExpressionStatement cannot start with the function keyword because that might make it ambiguous with a FunctionDeclaration.

To make it evaluate as an *expression*, it needs to be the right-hand side of an assignment, wrapped in parentheses or preceded by an operator. (`!{a:1,b:2}`)

Comment: `!{a:1}` doesn't really help when you want the value though ;)

Comment: @minitech: Nope, but it does force expression evaluation.  As a practical application, you can use that property to shave a byte off of self-executing functions: `!function(){...}();` instead of the traditional `(function(){...})();`

Answer (score 7):

```
 { a: 1, b: 2 }
```

is a code block, with two wrongly [labelled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) variables.

To create an object, surround the code block by parentheses, so that the braces are interpreted as object literals:

```
({ a: 1, b: 2 })
```

Comment: Interestingly enough, labelled variables work. It's the comma that's the problem, and if you change it to a semicolon it works too. Strange. You can embed URLs in JavaScript too then...

Answer (score 4):

It's because an opening `{` with no context is interpreted as the beginning of a block. You can use parentheses:

```
({ a: 1, b: 2 })
```

As it is though, it's just a block of execution - like one might find after an `if` or `for`. So you can type:

```
{alert("Hello!");}
```

[Here's more about that.](http://minitechme.blogspot.com/2012/01/wtf-2-blocks.html) Blocks sort of return values too, which is both awesome and disappointing.

Answer (score 2):

Because `{ a: 1, b: 2 }` is not a valid expression to execute. JavaScript looks it like a block of code since it starts and ends to curly braces.

If you try `({ a: 1, b: 2 })`, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

> Because your statement is being evaluated as a block, not an object literal declaration.

True josh

If you want it to be evaluated as an object, just write :

```
> ({a : 1, b : 2})
Object
a: 1
b: 2
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
({ "a" : 1, "b" : 2 })
```