# "SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" when inputting { "a": "", "b": "" } json in console

Tags: javascript, json, syntax-error, object-literal

I'm getting errors, in both chrome and firefox developer tools, when trying to evaluate the following:

```
{
    "a": "",
    "b": ""
}
```

jsonlint.com tells me it's valid. Putting this code in an actual javascript file and running it works fine. The strangeness shows up only when I run this in the console in chrome developer tools or firebug. What's going on here?

Comment: Works for me in Firebug, or at least, it will parse it if I assign that object to a variable. I get a different error just using the object entirely on its own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Defining a JavaScript object in console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082110/defining-a-javascript-object-in-console)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't execute JSON in the console. The JavaScript engine thinks its a block statement, with a label.

So this:

```
{
    "a": "", "b": ""
}
```

is interpreted as a block statement. <strike>The `"a":` part is interpreted as a label. The `"", "b"`
part is interpreted as an expression (two string literals and a comma operator in-between). Now the second `:` character is invalid in that position...</strike> Next, the `"a"` is interpreted as a string literal, and the `:` is not valid at that position.

You work with JSON like so:

1. You put it in a `.json` file,
2. You retrieve it via Ajax as a string,
3. You parse the string into an object with `JSON.parse()`.

(You can also keep JSON data as a string in a variable, for instance, or in the `localStorage` object. Either way, in regard to JavaScript, JSON data should always come as a string value.)

Comment: Thank you sir, I was going bloody mad over that. had to assign it to a variable to get chrome to show it, `a = {"foo": "bar"}`

Answer (score 7):

Actually, for one-off testing (my main use of the debug console), you *can* enter JSON object syntax, but you have to assign it to a variable:

```
> var x ={
    "a": "",
    "b": ""
  }
undefined

> x
Object
  a: ""
  b: ""
  __proto__: Object
```