# Entering Multi-Property Object in Dev Console Throws Error

Tags: javascript, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I've encountered some behavior in the Chrome Dev Console (and Firebug) that I don't quite understand...

If I enter a *multi-property* JSON object directly into the console, I get the following error:

[image]

The result I would expect is that the object would be returned exactly as I entered it, much like as if I were to directly enter a String or Number value.

Note, this is a different result then if I were to enter a *single-property* object:

[image]

What's going on here? Why is it throwing a SyntaxError?

Comment: Wrap it in parentheses, the opening bracket is being interpreted as a block delimiter, not an object literal.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" when inputting { "a": "", "b": "" } json in console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10537992/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-when-inputting-a-b-json-in-co)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluating an object directly in the Console works as of Chrome 66.

[image: object in console]

Answer (score 1):

The console evaluates whatever you enter. If you `eval()` your JSON object directly you get the same results.

```
eval("{foo1: 1, foo2: 2}")
// SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

If you assign your object to a variable then there's no syntax error.

```
// in console
> var foo = {foo1: 1, foo2: 2};
undefined
> foo
Object {foo1: 1, foo2: 2}
```