# Parentheses in an object literal

Tags: javascript, node.js, stringify

Are parentheses in an object literal simply the grouping operator?

[node-stringify](https://github.com/fuqcool/node-stringify) will convert:

```
 [ { a: 1 } ]
```

to the string:

```
 [({'a':1}),({'a':2})]
```

Can I take it that the parentheses here have no impact to the data, ie it is totally the same even if the parentheses are absent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `(...)` in this case is simply being used for grouping an expression. Omitting the parentheses would have no impact on your current data structure.

Parentheses can become more useful in situations where object literals might be interpreted as a [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) instead, e.g. when evaluating an expression in the developer console or when used inside ES6 Arrow functions:

```js
const first = () => {a: 1}
const second = () => ({a: 1})

console.log(first()) //=> undefined
console.log(second()) //=> {a: 1}
```

I suspect this is why `node-stringify` has nominated to include them in its output ― to avoid ambiguity wherever possible.

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis are so the the result works with `eval` which, specifically, is how they test the functionality in the spec file.

On the [GitHub page](https://github.com/fuqcool/node-stringify) itself they state:

> ```
> // The parenthesis is to make the result work with `eval`
> console.assert(stringify({a: 1, b: 2}) === '({a:1,b:2})');
> ```

**To explain further:** Normally, `eval` interprets the `{` token as the start of a block, not as the start of an object literal. By wrapping the object in parentheses eval interprets it as a full *expression* and, thusly, returns the parsed object literal correctly, which is important for the authors tests and otherwise not important for other implementations (as you've already noticed).

Comment: But in this case, at least, ` [ { a: 1 } ]` would pass through `eval` just fine even without the added parentheses.

Comment: @torazaburo True, but if you look at the code for node-strjngify it simply a recursive function so the two object literals inside are "stringified" and returned separately.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why node-stringify is putting parentheses around the objects like you describe. But yes, the data structure is the same with or without the parentheses.

Here's an example of `JSON.stringify` in the browser:

```js
var data = [
  {
    'a':1
  },
  {
    'a':2
  }
];

var stringified = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log(stringified);
```

Comment: @OldGeezer—who is/are "they"?

Comment: Author(s) of `node-stringify`, link in the answer by @rgthree.