# Why does "[] + {} === {} + []" evaluate to "true"?

Tags: javascript

If you open your JS console and type in `[] + {} === {} + []` it tells you it's true.

I don't understand why this is. I attempted to look up at how it's parsed.

For `[] + {}` the `+` here is the addition operator as operands are both literals. LHS doesn't yield a number through `.valueOf()` so it performs string concatenation using `.toString()` on both operands giving us `""` + `"[object Object]"`

For `{} + []` the `{}` is an empty code block and is 'ignored', the `+` operator here is parsed as the unary plus operator, it converts its operand to a Number. Empty arrays converted to a number become `0`

So this is appears to be `"[object Object]" === 0` which surely should be false?.

The identity operator checks if the two operands are equal without type conversion. I can't see how this ever coud be true. What part of the story am I missing?

Edit:

I see if you type `({} + [])` it parses it as an empty object making the RHS equal to "[object Object]". I looked this up and `( )` is the grouping operator. So perhaps this has something to do with this?

This is not a duplicate of [What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the). Answer bullet points 1 === 2  should NOT be true.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032856/what-is-the-explanation-for-these-bizarre-javascript-behaviours-mentioned-in-the And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438034/why-is-no-longer-nan-in-chrome-console

Comment: Empty object parameters return an object constructor also == `true` and an empty array is also a constructor object which return true

Comment: `{}` can't possibly be interpreted as an empty block, since it comes immediately after `===` (and `[] + {} ===` is not a valid statement in itself).

Comment: Ah good point. so RHS would evaluate to empty object + array. So both sides would equate to "object Object" so statement in question would be true. Cool, thanks.

Comment: Not really a WTF, just misunderstanding of the interpreter! :)

Comment: `([] + {}) === ({} + [])` is true too

Comment: http://www.2ality.com/2012/01/object-plus-object.html

Comment: It's point 2 of the "not a duplicate". It exactly explains what happens `[] + {}` evaluates to `"[object Object]"` - the _string_, and then `{} + []` does the exact same thing. The fact that it looks like point 3 in the other question is irrelevant, because the driving thing there is `{}` being the _first_ thing on the line - that makes it be an empty block. In this case, it's exactly equivalent to `{} + []` as it produces `"[object Object]"`.

Comment: Hmm okay, so why then does `{} + [] === [] + {}` LHS should be 0 as first thing on line makes it empty block, RHS is "[object Object]"?

Comment: "So this is appears to be "[object Object]" === 0 which surely shouldn't be false?." Don't you mean "shouldn't be true" or "should be false", or did I completely misunderstand the question?

Comment: @SoonDead http://i.stack.imgur.com/SILP9.png take _that_, strict equality!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The second point [in this magnificent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9033306/3689450) explains what happens when you "add together" an array and an object.

```js
var result = [] + {};

console.log(result);
console.log(typeof result);
```

What you get is the *string* `[object Object]` because each of the arguments is converted to a string. For an array, that results in calling `.join()` on it, which in turn, results in an empty string. For Objects, it produces the string `"[object Object]"` - adding them together leaves the second string.

The same happens on both sides of the comparison - on the right hand side, the order is different but that does not matter. The result will *not* be the same as point 3 in the answer, for the difference is that there `{} + []` is in the beginning of the line, so `{}` is interpreted as an empty block. In this situation it will (correctly) be interpreted as a plain object notation). The same casting logic will be performed and it will produce the same string as before: `"[object Object]"`

So, in the end, you are comparing `"[object Object]" === "[object Object]"` which returns `true`.

Note that `{} + [] === [] + {}` will *not* produce the same - again, due to point 3 of the linked answer  - the first `{}` will be interpreted as an empty block, so the left hand side becomes `+[]` which converts the array to a number, hence the result of the comparison will be `false`. **However** if you test this expression in the Chrome dev tools you will indeed get `true`. This is because [Chrome will auto-wrap your expression in parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438034/why-is-no-longer-nan-in-chrome-console?noredirect=1&lq=1) which forces the initial `{}` to be interpreted as an object. Checking `{} + [] === [] + {}` in Firefox or Node REPL or others should produce the "correct" `false`.

Comment: I cannot figure out the formatting on this.
But, Node says you're wrong about that.

`> {} + []
    0
    > [] + {}
    '[object Object]'
    > {} + [] === [] + {}
    true
    >`

Comment: @EricBlade hmm, interesting. I cannot replicate it, but it might be something to do with the NodeJS installation. That's certainly how it worked back when I wrote that answer and since I don't have it installed right now, I used [this online REPL service](https://repl.it/languages/Nodejs) which is running v9.7.1 and does return `false` for `{} + [] === [] + {}`. I'm not sure why you're getting a different result but it might be that your installation is doing the Chrome "trick" and actually evaluating `({} + [] === [] + {})` - might be a setting for it or a new feature from the latest version.

Answer (score 6):

```js
    var array = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
    var emptyObject = {}

    console.log(typeof(array+emptyObject));
    console.log(array+emptyObject);
    console.log(emptyObject+array);
    console.log(array+emptyObject === emptyObject+array);

    var array = [];
    var emptyObject = {}

    console.log(typeof(array+emptyObject));
    console.log(array+emptyObject);
    console.log(emptyObject+array);
    console.log(array+emptyObject === emptyObject+array);

    var array = ['firstArrayElement', 'secondArrayElement'];
    var object = {a:1, b:2}
    
    console.log(typeof(array+object));
    console.log(array+object);
    console.log(object+array);
    console.log(array+object === object+array);

    console.log(['a','b']+['c','d']);
```

When you convert an empty array to string you will receive empty string.

When you convert an object({}) to string you will always receive string: "[object Object]".

**Plus operator is not defined for arrays and objects** so JS always convert array and object to string when you use plus operator.