# Node JS / V8 destructuring bug?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, v8, destructuring

Using node 8.4.0:

```
$ node
> {x, y} = {x: 1, y: 2}
{ x: 1, y: 2 }
>
```

However, the following errors also non interactive: (the only diff is the semicolon)

```
$ node
> {x, y} = {x: 1, y: 2};
...
```

Also in Chrome console:

```
> {x,y} = {x:1, y:2}
< {x: 1, y: 2}
> {x,y} = {x:1, y:2};
x VM253:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

Can anyone explain this?

### Clarification

This is not about let, var or cosnt destructuring which works as intended. This is about previously defined variables, (or non strict mode): from chrome console:

```
> let a, b;
< undefined
> [a, b] = [1, 2];
< >(2) [1, 2]
> a
< 1
> b
< 2
> {a, b} = {a:3, b:4}
< >{a: 3, b: 4}
> a
< 3
> b
< 4
> {a, b} = {a:3, b:4};
x VM1297:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

Comment: Surely you need a declarator keyword like `const`, `let`, or `var`.

Comment: @Pointy, not correct if the variable was previously defined or not in strict mode. (no such problem with destructuring arrays, I use all the time)

Comment: And yet adding it does in fact allow you to conclude the statement.

Comment: @paul, sure that is not the potential bug I'm pointing at.

Comment: I'll clarify the question.

Comment: You'll want to have a look at [Why is {} + {} no longer NaN in Chrome console?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36438034/1048572), which explains how the semicolon-less statements get the parentheses they need to become valid (as per the answers below).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper syntax to destructure an object to existing variables is

```
({x, y} = {x: 1, y: 2});
```

This allows `{x, y} = {x: 1, y: 2}` to be an expression. Otherwise `{x, y}` is interpreted as a block with comma operator, this results in `Unexpected token =` error.

It works without parentheses and a semicolon in console because it is treated as an expression there. This is efficiently same thing as

```
console.log({x, y} = {x: 1, y: 2});
```

Answer (score 6):

It is not a bug but by design. See "[Assignment without declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration)":

> A variable can be assigned its value with destructuring separate from its declaration.
>
> ```
> var a, b;
> ({a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2});
> ```
>
> The `( .. )` around the assignment statement is required syntax when using object literal destructuring assignment without a declaration.
>
> `{a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}` is not valid stand-alone syntax, as the `{a, b}` on the left-hand side is considered a block and not an object literal.
>
> However, `({a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2})` is valid, as is `var {a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}`