# Destructuring assignment in React or nodejs

Tags: javascript

What are the drawbacks of using destructuring assignment in JavaScript? Anything to keep in mind while using in react or nodejs?

Comment: React is a JavaScript framework. Node.js is a JavaScript interpreter. I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 hes talking about a javascript language feature... which both use

Comment: @floor Remind me, what does a JavaScript feature have to do with a framework? It's like saying *anything to keep in mind while using additions in calculus?*

Comment: Destructing offers benefits over drawbacks. linting standards want you to use `let/const { someVar } = this;` over `let/const someVar = this.someVar;` because by spelling it once, it reduces the chance of error by typo

Comment: Drawbacks? It requires an ES6 environment, and you can do very confusing stuff with it, so use it with care.

Answer (score 3):

There are not really any drawbacks that don't exist for other convenience features.

The primary thing to keep in mind is not to forget the let, var, const keyword. Otherwise all destructured may become global.

**let** { a,b,c } = myObj;

Comment: If you forget `let`/`var`/`const` [you will get a SyntaxError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103157/node-js-v8-destructuring-bug).

Comment: Luckily if you omit the keyword, it's a syntax error :-)

Comment: guess I never have :-). hehe