# Why do {} and {}; evaluate differently in JS?

Tags: javascript

In Mac Chrome JS console, I experience the following results:

{} evaluates to Object()

{}; evaluates to undefined

How does the semicolon affect what comes before it?

Is this related to ASI, or another rule of parsing?

Comment: The Chrome console does what it does. It doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question.  It may be related to another question and answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438034/why-is-no-longer-nan-in-chrome-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome actually evaluates `{}` as if you've written `({})`, thus forcing the interpreter to treat is as *object literal* as opposed to an empty block;

```js
{ 
  console.log("the line starts with { so it's treated is an empty block, not an object");
}

({}) //this is an object that is discarded after the line is read
```

To illustrate that it's *actually* an empty block, see this code:

```js
{} == {} //syntax error because the effective code is "== {}"
```

And compare with this code

```js
({}) == {} //force the left side to be an object
```

In the above, the there is no error because it's evaluated correctly and then the result is dropped.

The following, however is a syntax error, so in *that* case Chrome silently drops the braces

```js
({};)
```

Comment: Apparently in addition to ASI, we must also consider API.  (Automatic Parentheses Insertion)

Answer (score 0):

This is because JS interprets `{}` as an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals), while `{};` turns to a [code block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).
This can be avoided by putting that in a pair of parentheses: `({});` will return an object.

Comment: That's not what happens