# Why does Firefox throw an error for the literal {"a": 1} while Chrome accepts it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, console, syntax-error

In Firefox console it throws an error because of the colon:

```
{"a": 1}

SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'
```

In Chrome console it accepts it:

```
{"a": 1}
{a: 1}
```

I know both accepts `{a: 1}`, I'd like to know why Firefox chokes on the string key version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See

[Why is {} + {} no longer NaN in Chrome console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438034/why-is-no-longer-nan-in-chrome-console)

> Chrome devtools now automatically wrap everything that begins with `{` and ends with `}` in an implicit pair of parentheses ([see code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/4fd348fdb9c0b3842829acdfb2b82c86dacd8e0a%5E!/#F2)), to force its evaluation as an expression.

Firefox does not do this. In Firefox,

```
{a: 1}
```

is evaluated as a block, which has a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) of `a`, with an unused expression `1`:

```
{
  a:
  1
}
```

(this is why, in FF, you see that the final expression evaluated is `1`:

[image]

)

But labels cannot be enclosed in string delimiters (labels need to have the *plain identifier only*, just like a variable), so changing the `a:` to `"a":` throws an error, because colons can only be parsed when after a label, or between a key-value pair in an object.

Comment: Interesting.. I often paste value expressions into the firefox console and I always assumed they are parsed as expressions, because it worked fine. Looks like i was just like lucky that they were e.g. wrapped in arrays, so they were evaluated properly:  [{"a" : 1}]