# Why does {} + [] evaluate to 0?

Tags: javascript, browser

My understanding is that:

> For `[] + []` and `[] + {}`, the `+` operator is interpreted as *string*
>   *concatenation*, values coerced to strings, so the expressions evaluate to `""` and `"[object Object]"`.
>
> For `{} + {}`, different browser engines interpret it as either *string*
>   *concatenation* or *addition*, so the results vary (`"[object Object][object Object]"`
>   in **Chrome** or `NaN` in **Firefox**).

Why does `{} + []` evaluate to `0`?

My line of thinking is that `+` is interpreted as *addition*, so `{}` should be coerced to `NaN` and `[]` to `0`. Then why doesn't the above expression evaluate to `NaN + 0` i.e. `NaN`?

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202157/why-does-return-the-string-10?rq=1

Comment: `{}` is an empty code block, so the *actual* expression being evaluated is `+ []` or unary plus followed by an empty array. This will transform the empty array to a number and that number is zero.

Comment: "*For `{} + {}`, different browser engines interpret it as either string concatenation or addition, so the results vary ("`[object Object][object Object]`" in Chrome or `NaN` in Firefox).*" actually, this is not very correct. Different browser engines will evaluate it *exactly* the same. It's the same logic `{}` is an empty code block then you have `+ {}` which will convert an object to a number and that's `NaN`. However, the Chrome console [cheats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438034/why-is-no-longer-nan-in-chrome-console) and evaluates `({} + {})`

Comment: which will *change* how this is parsed. You will get exactly the same result if you manually do `({} + {})` in the FF console. With the round brackets, this is *now* evaluated as two objects being joined by `+`. Note that in an actual file `{}` at the start of the line is *still* treated as an empty block, so `{} + {}` will produce `NaN` (and throw it away).

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!