# Why is semicolon changing JavaScript behavior in the Chrome console

Tags: javascript

This code executes perfectly in the **google chrome console**:

```js
{ a, b } = { a: 10, b: 20 }
```

> {a: 10, b: 20}

But when I add semicolon at the end, I get syntax error:

```js
{ a, b } = { a: 10, b: 20 };
```

> VM115:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='

Can someone tell me why? AFAIK `;` should not affect the meaning in javascript but apparently it does in google chrome console.

P.S. Please pay attention that this behavior is only observed in Google Chrome console.

Comment: Both these are syntax errors for me (firefox JS console). Semicolon does not, indeed, make a difference.

Comment: @Quentin I wanted to write an answer, which got converted into a comment for being trivial, so I deleted the comment and wrote an answer that's one sentence longer. Do you think we should dupe-close this?

Comment: Duplicate of [Object destructuring in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62572662) and [Having semicolon after spread syntax jn javascript breaks execution with error “Unexpected token =”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51003328) and [Why is {} + {} no longer NaN in Chrome console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438034) and [Node JS / V8 destructuring bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103157)

Comment: @Bergi — It does seem to be a pretty close match. Possibly sufficiently different to justify its own question though.

Comment: @adiga Ah, the "*Node JS / V8 destructuring bug?*" one seems to be a perfect duplicate. I hadn't known that

Answer (score 6):

[object destructuring without var](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27386234/object-destructuring-without-var) is only valid with parenthesis around the assignment expression - a statement must not begin with `{` in JavaScript, it would be a block otherwise.

The behaviour you experience comes from [the special handling of inputs that begin with `{` and end with `}` in the Chrome devtools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36438289/1048572). This heuristic is sometimes useful, but causes lots of confusion in cases where it goes wrong.