# Is hoisting of 'let' variables different for local and global scopes?

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying out the code snippets below -

1)

```
console.log(a);
let a = 5;
```

I get - Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
at :1:13

2)

```
a = 10;
let a = 5;
```

I get - Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'a' before initialization
at :1:3

If I try out the same snippets inside a function -

3)

```
function someName() {
    console.log(a);
    let a = 5;    
}
someName()
```

I get - Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'a' before initialization
at someName (:2:17)
at :1:1

4)

```
function someName() {
        a = 10;
        let a = 5;    
}
someName()
```

I get - Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'a' before initialization
at someName (:2:11)
at :5:5

Why is there a difference in the error messages for 1) and 2) but not 3) and 4). Is 'let' hoisting different for global and local scopes?

Comment: Are you trying this in the console? Because only then does the behaviour make sense. In the console, the code would be executed line by line, so it's trying to do `console.log(a)` and it's undefined. It hasn't processed `let a` yet. In a function, the statements would already be parsed before executing it. If you try it in a proper JS file, it should be equivalent, as the script is parsed and declarations hoisted before the execution starts.

Comment: Yes, but if that is the case, shouldn't -
console.log(a);
var a = 5;
throw the same error?

Comment: @VLAZ - Also, shouldn't -
a = 10;
let a = 5;
VM9983:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'a' before initialization
    at <anonymous>:1:3
Not throw an error, and just initialize a as a global variable?
Seems like there is some compilation of the entire code, before a line-by-line execution.

Comment: @AditiGarg where are you executing this? I tried code 1) in FF and Chrome and both give me (essentially) the same error "ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'a' before initialization" (FF) and "ReferenceError: Cannot access 'a' before initialization" (Chrome).

Comment: @VLAZ - Executing it in chrome Version 80.0.3987.132 for MacOS.

Comment: `a = 10; let a = 5;` - why do you think that this should not throw an error and initialize `a` as a global variable? Because of Temporal Dead Zone, you _cannot_ access an identifier declared with either `let` or `const` _until_ its declaration has executed during step-by-step execution of the code.

Comment: @Yousaf - As per VLAZ's first comment - In the console, the code would be executed line by line, so it's trying to do console.log(a) and it's undefined. 
Similarly, when a = 10; is executed, the console is unaware of the next line. So 'a' should just be initialized as a global variable and assigned the value 10.

Comment: As I said, I tested 1) and it gives the correct error in both FF and Chrome. Seems like the console execution has been improved since the last time I looked into it. So, I'm not really sure why you're getting that. My version of Chrome was actually older (v75), I'm updating to see how it works with a more recent one. But the only explanation for the first result is that it's executed line by line *and* you have strict mode on. I cannot find an environment that does that, though.

Comment: @VLAZ - true. Looks like it's a console peculiarity. I tried the same code in a js file, and got the expected result. Thank you.

Comment: I just tested `console.log(a); var a = 5;` and `a = 10; let a = 5;` in the chrome (Version 89.0.4389.90) console and results can only be explained if there's some compilation/parsing step involved,

Comment: `console.log(a); let a = 5;` does actually throw "*ReferenceError: a is not defined*" in Chrome v89. So, at least as far back as v75 it worked "correctly". However, I wouldn't really trust the console to show "correct" behaviours. There are all sorts of tricky things that can happen. The Chrome console in particular "cheats" by modifying how the code gets executed *in some circumstances* (e.g., try `{a: 1}` vs `{a: 1};`). FF is a bit better as it doesn't inject magic but I'd still not draw any hard conclusions from code executed there.

Comment: See [Why is {} + {} no longer NaN in Chrome console?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36438034) for an example of "magic" that the Chrome console does.