# {1:'a'}[1] This syntax works in code but not in the browser's developer tools?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

I've taken on a new project,and there's a line of code that looks like this:

```js
typeName() {
      return {
        1: 'leads',
        2: 'cunstomer',
        3: 'business'
      }[this.optionValue]
    },
```

it works well.
I've never seen before.
Then I tried in developer tools,but it don't work!
Can anyone tell me why?

[image]

```js
{1:'a'}[1]
```

Developer tools will report the error:Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Comment: because, without the `return` the code  `{...}` is simply a block of code - try either `({1:'a'}[1])` or `({1:'a'})[1]`

Comment: Might be related: [Why is {} + {} no longer NaN in Chrome console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36438034/why-is-no-longer-nan-in-chrome-console)

Comment: By the way, `{ a: 1 }[0]` would be syntactically valid JS, a block statement with a label inside, followed by an array literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript expects an **expression** after the keyword `return`. The dev tools console expects more or less what you would put in a file: a **statement**.

#### Edit

As stated in the comment by [Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5260024/jonas-wilms), statement are themselves expressions. And, given that certain syntax is used for both statements and expressions, whenever there is conflict, the statement takes precedence.

For example, the statement:

```js
if (5 > 3) {
  console.log(33);
}
```

is valid as console input, but not as a return value:

```js
function myFunc() {
  
  // return expects an expression
  return if (5 > 3) {
    console.log(33)
  }
}
```

What you are essentially doing is putting a number inside a code block (a **statement**) with a colon afterwards and then trying to index that block.

```js
// This makes no sense in the global scope

{
  1:'a'
}[1]
```

Comment: This is not quite correct as every expression is a statement in JavaScript. The main problem is that certain syntax is used for both statements and expressions, and then the statement syntax has precedence